# Session data lost before ticket timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies

I try to set a rather long session time of 60 minutes on my web site by setting in web.config the authentication / forms / timeout value, and also by setting in code behind of the login page FormsAuthenticationTicket.expiration. However, already in 20 minutes, way too early, data in my Session variable got lost. How does this work and how do I fix it?

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH" 
    loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
    protection="All" 
    timeout="60"                   /* <<------ */         
    slidingExpiration="true" 
    path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

login.aspx.cs:

```
            // Create a new ticket used for authentication
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,                                      // Ticket version
                LoggedInUser.LoginNm.ToString(),        // Username associated with ticket
                DateTime.Now,                           // Date/time issued
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), // <<---   // Date/time to expire, minutes, use same value as in web.config or result is unclear
                false,                                  // "true" for a persistent user cookie
                LoggedInUser.UserID.ToString(),         // User-data, in this case user object
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);   // Path cookie valid for

            // Encrypt the ticket and store in a cookie
            string CookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            string CookieValue = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName, CookieValue);

            // Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time, plus a little to be sure.
            // NB: the cookie is created and updated with "sliding" reset automatically
            //  if the SetAuth...()  coockie call was used
            // NB: Persistent is false, so this is a Session cookie without expiration 
            //     that is deleted when the browser closes.
            //if (ticket.IsPersistent)
            {
                cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration.AddMinutes(5);
            }
```

Check if the session is still alive in a form.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load settings from session variabele
    MySession = Session["MySession"] as ClSession;
    // return to loginpage indien sessionvar = null
    if (MySession == null)
        Response.Redirect("~/SessionExpired.html"); // <<---after only 20 minutes!!??
    return;
}
```

Comment: Let's see the session state portion of the web.config -- what mode it is set to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx session is different mechanism than forms ticket.  Both need to be configured in tandem to get the desired result.

Comment: Good question. I don't have that section. I will try this: `<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />`

Comment: That did it, thanks! If it where an Answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: With InProc mode you'll still lose sessions every now and again one you deploy to production.  This is because the session is stored "in process" and if the application pool recycles the session will be lost.  The way around that is to go with State server or SQL, etc.  InProc is kind of like a toy session mode I don't even know why they have that option honestly.

Comment: Thanks for explaining details. Even then, this is still a huge improvement over not having the sessionState at all. InProc must be the default mode, so we are used to that for years. Now I know how to set the timeout. Is there an event in Global.asax.cs to keep track of recycling? Probably Application_End?